# Expo secrets returning null when accessing in app code on an expo react native app through all build profiles

Tags: react-native, expo, environment-variables, eas

I've setup an account wide environment variable and I'm having trouble retrieving it in my application code in a production build.

eas.json

```
...
"build": {
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      }
    },
    "staging": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m1-medium"
      },
      "extends": "production"
    }
  },
...
```

app.config.js

```
import "dotenv/config";

export default () => ({
...
extra: {
  GOOGLE_API_KEY: process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY || null
},
...

})
```

Application Code

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
...
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = Constants.expoConfig.extra.GOOGLE_API_KEY
...
```

The constant is undefined for all build types and the only way I am able to successfully retrieve the environment variable is when I create a dev server with the following parameter:

`GOOGLE_API_KEY="..." npx expo start`

I am expecting the constant to be defined, and work throughout all eas build profiles. What am I mistaken with here?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem and can't find any information

Comment: @MatheusAlves nope, was not able to figure this out. Seems like a reoccurring issue throughout forms.

Comment: my solution was to set the variables in the build object inside my eas.json file and later access them as process.env....